# 2 authentication managers one authentication object

Tags: spring, security

I'm trying to protect a resource by defining 2 HTTP elements and 2 authentication managers. Each HTTP element has a separate form to authenticate with. The first form and HTTP element is needed to access any resource. The second form is the authenticate with more complex authentication parameters (username, password, etc)

PROBLEM: When I have authenticated with first form to access the application, this works fine as expected, but then when I try to reach the second protected resource I never get to the form as it see's I need a new role (checks the auth object and fails as the role does not exist) here's where I'm a little lost.

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

```
<!-- Exclude public pages and static resources -->
<http pattern="/favicon.ico" security="none" />
<http pattern="/js/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/css/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/img/**" security="none" />

<http pattern="/test**" auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="smsAuthManager">            
    <intercept-url pattern="/test" access="hasRole('ROLE_SMS_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/refreshLoginPageTuring" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/loginTuring" access="hasRole('USER')" />
    <form-login login-page="/loginTuring" 
                login-processing-url="/test-login"
                 authentication-failure-url="/accessdenied"/>
    <logout logout-url="/logout" invalidate-session="true"/> 

    <!-- <access-denied-handler ref="/loginTuring"/> -->     
</http>

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="userPortal">
    <intercept-url pattern="/getQRCode" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/refreshLoginPageTuring" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/accessdenied" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="hasRole('USER')" />  

    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/menu"
        authentication-failure-url="/accessdenied" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/errors/error" access="hasRole('USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/menu" access="hasRole('USER')" />
</http> 

<authentication-manager id="userPortal">
    <authentication-provider ref="userPortalAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager> 

<authentication-manager id="smsAuthManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="smsAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>
```

FORM:

```
<form id="form1" action="/test-login" method="post">
                    <label for="j_username"><spring:message code = "login.username" /></label>
            <input id="j_username" value="${username}" name="j_username" type="text">

            <label for="j_password"><spring:message code = "login.password" /></label>
            <input id="j_password" value="${password}" name="j_password" type="password">

            <label for="otc"><spring:message code = "login.otc" /></label>
            <input id="otc" name="otc" type="password">

            <button name="submit" type="submit" id="login" onclick="return validateForm()" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>                               
            <button name="sessionstart" type="submit" id="sessionstart" onclick="return validateAndChangeToRefreshImgAction()" class="btn">Refresh Image</button>

            <br/>
            <input type="hidden" name="rmShown" value="1">                                          
            <img id="scimage" style="block" src="<c:url value="/img/empty.gif" />"/> 

        </form>
```

" method="post" class="login-form">

                    
                    " name="j_username" type="text">

Comment: UPDATE: <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('USER')" /> this is how I have defined the catch all. NOT <intercept-url pattern="/" access="hasRole('USER')" />

Comment: To be clear on the problem I can never reach the loginTuring form.